# Python из БД возвращается кортеж

Tags: python, sql

Есть следующий код:

```
    firecursor.execute(("SELECT customer_id FROM CUSTOMER WHERE customer_id=%s") %customer_id)
    fireselect_customer = firecursor.fetchall()
```

Проблема в том, что в fireselect_customer возвращается кортеж, а мне нужно или строку или число т.к. требуется провести булевую оценку вернулось ли что-то из БД или нет. Если нет, то выругаться.

Еще не могу понять, что в переменной кортеж или все же список. если делаю type то говорит, что список, а если пытаюсь список преобразовать в строку, то оно говорит, что с кортежом это делать нельзя.

Как быть?
\\\\\\\\\\
В итоге сделал так:

```
    fireselect_customer= str(fireselect_customer)
    print ("fireselect_customer: %s") %fireselect_customer
    # проверяем не пусто ли? Если не пусто то все ОК.
    print type(fireselect_customer)
    if not fireselect_customer:
```

Однако не могу понять как проверить не [] ли возвращается. Указанная проверка походу не работает т.к. на консоль дальше выводится не то, что нужно т.е. [] а пишет, что есть значение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

во первых: при работе с "сырыми курсорами" всегда возвращается массив строк из бд в виде кортежа [(x,...),(x,...)]
во вторых: для проверки на истинность есть вот такие правила:

```
[],(), {}, 0, "", None, False
```

все это эквивалентно при преобразовании в boolean, что легко доказать в консоли:

```
bool([]) == False
```

поэтому проверки на True/False стандатных типов данных сводятся к виду:

```
statement = [] # [1]
if statement: print True
else: print False
```

за одним исключением, когда идет проверка на None:
в пределах питона существует только один единственный объект None (singleton pattern) поэтом рекомендуется условие вида (в целях оптимизации):

```
if statement is None # is not None
```